# Computer/Technology oriented tourist attractions

Tags: europe, geek-travel

In a few weeks I will be visiting Germany. I've already picked out a few historical sites, some architectural/art museums, and a ski resort that I'm planning on visiting but there's one thing I'm having trouble finding anything on or if such an attractions exists.

Are there any sort of computer/technology oriented tourist attractions/conferences in Germany or even in the surrounding area?

I'm having a hard time thinking of specific things I can actually Google for this. What I've tried has only turned up one actual result.

Comment: In the "nearby" category is Ars Electronica in Linz, Austria. I found it great, but perhaps I'm biased due to having some of my work on display there :)

Comment: http://www.technikum29.de/en/  and http://www.experiminta.de/abenteuer-informatik.html never been to these so won't make an answer

Answer (score 6):

In Hungary, you can visit the [informatics history exhibition](http://ajovomultja.hu/about?language=en) with some truly fascinating objects. Did you know the earliest hard case floppy was invented in Hungary in 1973 (!), [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_floppy_disk#The_3-inch_compact_floppy_disk) mentions it too. They have a robot built in 1956-57. It's absolutely fascinating and for us Hungarians really depressing how these never went anywhere due to the Cold War / Iron Curtain.

The address is

```
Szent-Györgyi Albert Agóra
6722 Szeged, Kálvária sgt. 23 .
Hungary
```

Szeged is an easy train ride from Budapest.

(I know to some Hungary might not be in the surrounding area of Germany but this is an absolutely unique exhibition. Most of these things you've never heard of and definitely would never ever see anywhere else.)

Comment: Are you suggesting he travels from Germany to Hungary for a museum?

Comment: Yes. It's not a big deal and a lifetime experience, depending of course how often he visits the EU. for eg. easyJet will get you from Berlin to Budapest for <50EUR in 1.5hrs.

Comment: Apart from telling about an alternative place, this answer also gives another idea on how to look for such places, I find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

Google told me about the Bielefelder (or Deutsches) Computermuseum.

http://www.deutsches-computermuseum.de/

... and about the Computermuseum München:

http://www.computermuseum-muenchen.de/

Some other relevant links from the results page:

http://www.deutsches-museum.de/en/exhibitions/communication/computers/
http://www.sdtb.de/Mathematics-and-Computer-Science.1256.0.html

Interestingly, as I typed "deutsches c" the only suggestion was "deutsches currywurst museum".  Perhaps the computer museums are less frequently sought than the currywurst museum; I don't know what that might imply about their quality.

Comment: "Perhaps the computer museums are less frequently sought than the currywurst museum; I don't know what that might imply about their quality." - it might simply imply what can be seen in your list: Most German computer museums are not named "Deutsches Computermuseum-something" ;)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on where you are, you may want to try the [*Zentrum für Kunst und Medientechnologie* (ZKM)](http://zkm.de/en/) in Karlsruhe (South-Western Germany) ([WP article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_for_Art_and_Media_Karlsruhe)).

It features various historical computing devices, but it also has a strong arts-related angle, so there are also many "interactive arts exhibits" that use multimedia technologies in one way or another.

Answer (score 2):

Depends a little on what you mean by the "surrounding area", but in Linz, Austria you'll find [Ars Electronica Center](https://ars.electronica.art).

I highly recommend checking out the "Panorama" exhibit, but mainly because several of the images used in it are mine.

Answer (score 2):

At least in South Germany there are a few famous ones:

- [Technology museum in Sinsheim](https://sinsheim.technik-museum.de/en/): Famous for the only place in the world with the two commercial super sonic passenger jets (Concorde, Tupolev TU-144), a huge formula 1 collection and many more tanks, cars and airplanes
- [Technology museum in Speyer](https://speyer.technik-museum.de/) (same association behind it as in Sinsheim): Famous for having a 747, an old german navy submarine, a Buran (the Russian version of the space shuttle) and many more exhibits
- [The Center for Culture and Media (ZKM)](https://zkm.de/en) in Karlsruhe: World famous for modern media based art exhibitions
- [The German Museum in Munich](https://www.deutsches-museum.de/en): Maybe slightly misnamed it is mainly a technology museum with a lot of interesting pieces and exhibitions